# WKWebView - Can't load page and set custom font/css with loadHTMLString

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, wkwebview

I am trying to download a online page and override css with my custom css. However I couldn't have success.

I did the following steps:

1. Download Html string from an online page
2. Added `"<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">"` to the page Html head. This styles.css contains a custom font and anothers css rules.
3. Loaded this new Html string to WKWebView with `webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: Bundle.main.bundleURL)`

Another option would be just download the page and override the css with a style tag between the head tag, however I need to add a custom @font-face from a font in my project resources.

Any ideas how can I accomplish this? If I set Bundle.main.bundleURL as my baseURL resources from the online page don't download. If I set nil as my baseURL I can't access my custom font...

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use bundlePath instead of bundleURL like this.

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.bundlePath)
webView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: url)
```

Comment: I have social feeds embeded to my web content and I lose them if I change baseURL.